# Testflight gives me "Developer Certificate Detected" with an Ad-Hoc profile

Tags: ios, cordova, testflight

1. I created a production certificate in Apple Developer center.
2. Used that to generate a P12 file.
3. Created an AD-HOC provisioning file using the production certificate (nothing else to choose)
4. Used that prov profile and the P12 to build the App in Phonegap.
5. Phonegap says everything is ok.
6. I then upload the IPA to testflight and I get the "Developer cert detected".

But this is a ADHOC profile, how can that ever be signed with a Developer cert??

Can you spot anything I'm doing wrong? On my 3GS the app is listed as incompatible. I  assume because I'm not in developer mode. But with ad-hoc that should not be needed right?

Comment: Have a look at your build settings and check for "Code Signing Entity" . Did you supply the distribution certificate for your release settings?

Comment: Where would I find that?

Comment: click on your project file in Xcode, select your Target and then find the "Build Settings" tab in the center view.

Comment: I had the same problem after I updated to Xcode 5.1. I solved the problem by signing the app afterwards through the website using the profile I downloaded from the Member Center. I wouldn't worry about that too much if you can solve the problem the way I did. Seems like you should find an alternative anyway: http://techcrunch.com/2014/02/21/rumor-testflight-owner-burstly-is-being-acquired-by-apple/

Comment: @SebastianBorggrewe &Paul: Xcode wasn't used. Installing the App using iTunes does work properly. TestFlight support is being vague. Im inclined to think it's a TestFlight bug (as iTunes installs just fine).